# Reader properties file with latin characters

Tags: java, spring, properties-file

I have a properties file with latin characters in it. When i read this properties file through spring using @resource my map is getting is populated but only with last character that to not in proper format.
Please can you let me know the reason for this and how it could be fixed?

```
á=a
é=e
```

entries in properties file as above.

Answer (score 2):

Java uses Unicode to define non-ASCI characters, thus you will need to replace them with [Unicode](https://unicode-table.com/en/#00E1) equivalent for Text or HTML code:

```
char|  code  | HTML
----+--------+-------
 á  | \u00E1 | &#225;
 é  | \u00E9 | &#233;
```